# else essentially superfluous

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I don't have a background in programming, so this is probably really dumb, but I've never considered this before: it seems that the `else` statement is essentially superfluous because when the condition is False, Python just moves to the next unindented line .

For example, normally you would write: (if not using `elif`)

```
x=2
if x == 1: 
    value = "one"
else:
    if x == 2:
        value = "two"
print value
```

But this works too:

```
x=2
if x == 1: 
    value = "one"
if x == 2:
    value = "two"
print value
```

Could someone give an example that shows how and when the `else:` statement is essential?

Comment: If you don't have the `else`, then the interpreter has to check whether `x == 2`, even if it already ran the `x == 1` branch. Behavior may be the same, but you're making the interpreter do more work. (And it may *not* be the same -- if there were another thread, or if `value` were a property with a setter that changed `x` when `one` was assigned, then it would actually *need* to do that work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the conditions are mutually exclusive then `else` is superfluous. It's not if the conditions overlap, though.

```
x = 2
if x > 0:
    print 'foo'
else:                   # better -- elif x > 1:
    if x > 1:
        print 'bar'
```

This program prints `foo`.

```
x = 2
if x > 0:
    print 'foo'
if x > 1:
    print 'bar'
```

This program prints `foo` `bar`.

Comment: It's never a must mate. You can just use `if 1 >= x > 0:` and `if x > 1:`

Comment: Being not superfluous means it's necessary AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

`else` *remembers* that the condition was `False`. For example, consider this code:

```
if x == 1:
    x = 2
    print("bar")
else:
   if x == 2:
       print("foo")
```

*With* the `else`, only one of "bar" or "foo" will be printed.

*Without* the `else`, both "bar" and "foo" can be printed since the value of `x` can change.

This also can help with 'overlapping' conditions:

```
if x > 10: 
    print("big")
elif x > 5: 
    print("medium")
elif x > 1:
    print("sizable")
else:
    print("small")
```

Answer (score 0):

Else is never a must but is rather a convenience. Here are some:

```
if x == 1: 
    value = "one"
else:
    value = "not_one"
```

or

```
if x < 1: 
    value = "less_than_one"
elif x < 2:
    value = "between_one_and_two"
else:
    value = "more_than_two"
```

---

They can both be rewritten as:

```
if x == 1: 
    value = "one"
if x != 1:
    value = "not_one"
```

or

```
if x < 1: 
    value = "less_than_one"
if 1 <= x < 2:
    value = "between_one_and_two"
if 2 <= x:
    value = "more_than_two"
```

Comment: In the first example, though, the else is not essential it seems.

Comment: Else is never a must. It is just convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` clause is useful if you are looking for a specific case (using `if`) and then everything else that is not covered by the `if` (using `else`).

Often a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) is used:

```
>>> x=3
>>> value='one' if x==1 else 'not one'
>>> value
'not one'
```

If you did not use an `else` here (either as part of the conditional or as part of an `if/else` then `value` would not de defined:

```
>>> del value   # remove the name `value`
>>> x
3
>>> if x==1: value='one'
... 
>>> value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

So you do need the `else` class to make sure that `value` received a assignment if x is not 1.

---

BTW, In Python, rather than long cascade of `if/elif/elif/else` you can use a dictionary with a default:

```
>>> conditions={1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'}
>>> conditions.get(2,'not one, two, or three...')
'two'
>>> conditions.get(19,'not one, two, or three...')
'not one, two, or three...'
```